# Cassandra CCM Error: "ccmlib.common.ArgumentError"

Tags: cassandra

I installed CCM utility of Cassandra, but when I try to create a cluster with the following command:

`root@ubuntu2:~# ccm create cluster1 -v=2.0.9`

I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ccm", line 5, in 
    pkg_resources.run_script('ccm==2.0', 'ccm')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 528, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1401, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm-2.0-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/ccm", line 72, in

File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/cmds/cluster_cmds.py", line 125, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/cluster.py", line 51, in **init**
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/cluster.py", line 64, in load_from_repository
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/repository.py", line 40, in setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ccmlib/repository.py", line 211, in download_version
**ccmlib.common.ArgumentError: Invalid version =2.0.9 (underlying error is: HTTP Error 404: Not Found)**

Changing to any other version of Cassandra in the command does not help.
There is no issue with Internet connection.

Will appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

Try ... -v 2.0.9

As the error suggests, the version number '=2.0.9' is not valid.